# Column with arrays to columns (Bigquery)

Tags: sql, dataframe, google-bigquery

I'm new to bigquery and dataframes and I want to do something on this following table:
[image: Table]

As you see, I've an array of itemid and its corresponding value on the value column for every person (They are the same length obviously). What I want to do is to create a column for each itemid and then have the value on that column for a specific person. For example, there will be columns named 51493, 51516 and so on, and for the first person the value on the column 51943 will be 2 and so on, and null for every other person who doesn't have a value for 51943.

I assume that parsing with a for inside a for loop is highly inefficient, and since I'm new to dataframes I would love some help on to do it efficiently.
Thanks!

To a request, this is the bigquery query that gave me this data:

```
%%bigquery lab_m_df
SELECT
  # MIMIC3 sets all ages over 89 to 300 to avoid the possibility of
  # identification.
  IF(DATETIME_DIFF(ADMITTIME, DOB, DAY)/365.25 < 200,
     DATETIME_DIFF(ADMITTIME, DOB, DAY)/365.25,
     # The life expectancy of a 90 year old is approximately 5 years according
     # to actuarial tables. So we'll use 95 as the mean age of 90+'s
     95) AS age,
  gender,
  admission_type,
  itemids,
  value,
  admission_location,
  insurance,
  marital_status,
  ethnicity,
  died
FROM
  (SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(ITEMID) as itemids,
    ARRAY_AGG(IFNULL(VALUE, 'null')) as value,
    MAX(HOSPITAL_EXPIRE_FLAG) as died,
    ANY_VALUE(ADMITTIME) as ADMITTIME,
    ANY_VALUE(ADMISSION_TYPE) as admission_type,
    ANY_VALUE(ADMISSION_LOCATION) as admission_location,
    ANY_VALUE(INSURANCE) as insurance,
    ANY_VALUE(MARITAL_STATUS) as marital_status,
    ANY_VALUE(ETHNICITY) as ethnicity, 
    HADM_ID,
    SUBJECT_ID
  FROM
    `{admissions_table}` AS adm
    JOIN `{labevents_table}` AS diag
  USING (HADM_ID, SUBJECT_ID)
  WHERE DATETIME_DIFF(CHARTTIME, ADMITTIME, HOUR) <= 4
  GROUP BY HADM_ID, SUBJECT_ID
  )
  JOIN `{patients_table}` AS patients
  USING (SUBJECT_ID)
```

Comment: Please show the data that you are starting with.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi, I've uploaded the bigquery query which gives me this table, since the data is big. But I assume this query is enough to understand the table im taking the data from, it is helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is quite tricky.  A better approach is a separate *row* for each pair:

```
select t.personid, itemid, val
from t cross join
     unnest(itemids) itemid with offset ni join
     unnest(value) val with offset nv
     on ni = nv;
```

If you know what items you care about, it is simple to generate the columns:

```
select t.personid,
       max(case when itemid = 1 then val end) as item1,
       max(case when itemid = 2 then val end) as item2,
       max(case when itemid = 3 then val end) as item3,
       . . .
from t cross join
     unnest(itemids) itemid with offset ni join
     unnest(value) val with offset nv
     on ni = nv
group by t.personid
```

Comment: I do know the items I care about. I care about specifically 40 itemid. Is there a way to create 40 columns in a more aesthetic way instead of doing 40 rows of    "max(case when itemid = 1 then val end) as item1"
?

Comment: @The_C . . . I would suggest just using the `max()` expressions.